# Access Electron API from a completely different system process

Tags: node.js, electron, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am looking for a way to capture a screenshot of a VS Code extension host window. This window is opened when my extension's tests are being run (this is coming from the default Yeoman template for VS Code extensions).

I cannot use my extension's context as the extension only has access to the VS Code API and VS Code runs extensions in a different Node process from the Electron one (main or renderer). IPC is used through the API instead of running extensions in-process.

I can run this code in an Electron renderer process (using DevTools or as a part of the Electron application's script) to capture the Electron window:

```
const electron = require('electron');
electron.remote.getCurrentWindow().capturePage(image => {
  //electron.clipboard.writeImage(image);
  electron.clipboard.writeText(image.toDataURL());
  console.log('Data URL is in clipboard.');
});
```

I have verified that placing this in VS Code window DevTools will produce the correct Data URI.

In order to be able to do this from a different Node process, knowing only the Code window PID, I figured I would attach a debugger to the VS Code extension host Electron window and using CDP I would issue a `Runtime.evaluate` call to run the above code as if it was entered into the DevTools.

However, I am struggling with attaching the debugger. There are generally two ways to do it:

- `kill -s SIGUSR1 <node-pid>` for Unix/macOS
- `process._debugProcess(proc.pid);` for Windows

I am interested in Windows right now, so I issue the Windows line from a new Node process. What should happen upon successful debugger attachment is the target process should print out something like this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/cf49bcfe-d922-4f89-b438-57755d254198
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

However in my case, this only works if I start the barebones Electron app with `--inspect` and then issue `process._debugProcess(proc.pid);`, without `--inspect` it doesn't throw an error, but doesn't attach the debugger either.

Comment: *Are there ways to pick an arbitrary system process (by PID for example), test it for being a Node process and prod into that process' JS context to be able to invoke the JS APIs in it?* - sounds like hacking. If it's your app, consider providing some sort of IPC (HTTP or else). See for instance, https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc

Comment: Considering you're asking this question, I guess you're out of luck. By 'hacking', I mean real hacking, specific to your OS. I'm not familiar with VS Code ecosystem. Would an extension that acts as a mediator get the access to API you need? You could install it ask it through IPC to make a screenshot, if this is possible.

Comment: Saw your GH issue. Yes, if it isn't possible, you're out of luck. If Electron app doesn't allow some way to hack into it (I suppose VS Code doesn't), it isn't any easier than hacking into any other random app and making it doing something. I guess your best bet is to make app-agnostic screenshots with https://github.com/johnvmt/node-desktop-screenshot . Or create a custom build of VS Code that allows to access Electron API somehow (CLI or IPC), if this works for you.

Comment: The above comments are now out of date as I've identified an approach which could work (debug protocol), but ran into a potential Electron Windows bug with that so the question pivoted to that. I've deleted my no longer valid comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process._debugProcess` now works for me with Electron 5.